# fix and process badly formed XML in VB.net

Tags: xml, regex, vb.net

I have been sent some bad data in XML, and was wondering if there is any way in vb.net to go through a string with XML data and safely sanitize any rubbish data I keep getting files which include `',<,>,&` inside attributes values and was wonder how best am I to go through and tidy up the badly formed XML..

Currently I just have a function that I keep adding string replacements to but the bad data can be random and it could be a while before I realize there is a problem.

I was wondering is there a way I could go through in reg-ex to fix this or is there a function in .NET that will safely convert bad XML into safe XML?

I know the easiest solution would be to change the source however this is not possible, as it is from a closed source legacy system.

Thanks Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most common bug when applications generate XML incorrectly is to fail to escape special characters such as "<", "&", and """. In some cases this bug will produce content that can't be recognized and repaired because it outputs XML that is well-formed (but not the XML intended).

Failing to escape """ in attributes is likely to be particularly hard to repair because the unescaped """ looks like the end of the attribute value, and the XML syntax error that results might be quite a bit later in the file.

Failing to escape "&" or "<" is a bit easier, most of the time, because you can detect when these characters are not followed by something that could legally follow them in well-formed XML - a name and semicolon in the case of '&', a name or "/name" or "!" in the case of "<". You're only going to catch 90% of the errors if this is what you look for, but that may be better than nothing.

Much better is to go back to the people who are sending you this garbage and get it fixed. They aren't doing anyone a service by sending out such rubbish.

Comment: I wish I could go back and get it sorted it has caused me more headaches then I care to remember

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your input by writing a function which replaces all these non-xml supported characters by iterating over each char and if the char doesn't fall between the < and > chars by respective xml entities.

For the complete list you can see in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Once you replace these chars, you arrive at a valid xml that you can parse using any XML parser.

Comment: Sorry I do know I need to replace the non-xml supported characters, however in a string how can I safley remove `'<>` what reside inside attributes and without messing with valid occurrences `'<>` such as attributes and elements

Comment: Sorry - I just missed putting a detail. Updated the post.